# How to make transparent text?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a portfolio and I'd like to know how to set a div property that makes the div's TEXT transparent and background and such opaque.

[image]

Comment: Use Canvas for this and create a Picture. Or better SVG with a text path

Comment: `color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` would be one way.

Comment: depends on your specification. CSS has a propperty called "opacity" which you can set in percentages.

Comment: Let this be a lesson to you: ask a vague question, get a lot of eye-rolling answers. With the example, this is actually a significantly harder question than the one we were answering. Off the top of my head, the SVG method might actually be easiest.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rgba` and set the opacity to 0 (the last value).

`color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ebr7gn6m/)

**UPDATE**

Now that you have clarified your question... SVG would be your best bet. See [fill-opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-opacity)

Comment: Actually better yet.... `color: transparent;`

Comment: @CodeiSir `color` is the css property for text color, `background-color` is for background and `opacity` is for everything

Comment: @CodeiSir he says with all caps that the TEXT needs to be transparent and the background opaque. Not really sure what you're on about. This does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the  `red,green,blue,alpha` value for the `color`

```css
div{

  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;

}
p{

font-size: 30px; 
font-weight: bolder;
color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> your text </p>  
</div>
```